# Implementing Axis Web service with certificates in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, certificate, axis

I'm about to implement a web service client against a web service, protected by a certificate and a password.

I received the password and the certificate (.p12) from the web service provider (an external partner).

The web service client is auto generated in Eclipse using Ajax (not Ajax 2). I tested the service against soapUI (where i created a mocked service), and it works perfect.

Now I need to implement the web service client, up against the real service and my question is simply; how do I add the certificate and the password to the webservice in Eclipse?

Comment: What authentication system is used by your provider? HTTPS client authentication or XML signatures? Both may be applicable using a P12 file containing a certificate and a private key.

Comment: HTTPS client authentication, and sorry for my late answer :) Merry Xmas